# Control access to Firestore documents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a mock app which allows users to upload "reports". These reports are stamped with a "creatorId", which is the uid of the user who creates the report.

I'm trying to use firebase queries to only request documents whose creatorId matches the currently logged in user's uid, to prevent requests for another user's documents.

I just can't seem to get it to work. I can make it work for collections easy peasy, but can't figure it out for individual docs.

```
const ref = projectFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id)
```

This is part of my useDocument hook, to which I pass "reports" and the id in question just fine, but this allows me to access the doc even if it has a creatorId which doesn't match the currently logged in user.

My query is:

```
["creatorId", "==", user.uid]
```

Which I also pass into the hook as a prop, but I cannot for the life of me figure where to put it - the query seems to be completely ignored whatever I do, and so the doc remains open to any and all. I think I am going mad.

Comment: If u want to prevent users from seeing documents created by another users you want to check firestore rules:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client app code can never be trusted to do the right thing, since it's running on a machine you don't control.  If you want to restrict access to documents, you will need to learn about [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics).  In particular, you will want to study how to limit access to documents [using the currently signed in user's UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. Right now I've locked access to only the document creator, but later I will also be allowing access to different roles of varying "seniority" within the hypothetical organisation. Thank you very much again.